# Why does Sendkeys not work on input field after website update? - Excel VBA Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a short script to log me in to the following page automaticaly, however last week it stopped to work and I cannot figure out why.

This is the url:
https://partner.spreadshirt.de/login

II am using Excel Vba with the selenium and the chromewebdriver. I taught myself how to write code in VBA so I don't know if I am describing everything in a proper way. 
I assume it has to be with the autofocus attribute or the nonvalidate, but I might also be wrong

I tried every variation of addressing via css ("input#username", "#loginForm #username"), what else can I try?

I also tried looking for a solution on stackoverflow, but if you don't know what to look for it is a little bit difficult, if you could point me in the right direction or explain why my approach didn't work I am always happy to learn!

```
Public Sub Login()

    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

    driver.Get "https://partner.spreadshirt.de/login"

    driver.FindElementByCss("#username").SendKeys ("username")

End Sub
```

I want a quick way to login so I don't have to do it manually. It was working in the past, but in the last update they changed the Css ID and apparently something else I am not able to figure out :-)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error message do u see, when its failing?

Comment: @IPolnik I am getting the NoSuchElementError saying "Element not found for css="#username"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `iframe` .You need to switch to `iframe` to access the element.

```
Public Sub Login()

    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

    driver.Get "https://partner.spreadshirt.de/login"
    driver.SwitchToFrame.FindElementById("central-login-iframe")
    driver.FindElementByCss("#username").SendKeys ("username")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for also showing me how it is done!

Comment: @KunduK Why I got error at this line `driver.SwitchToFrame.FindElementById ("central-login-iframe")` .. but works fine when change to `driver.SwitchToFrame "central-login-iframe"`?

Comment: @YasserKhalil : I think it is been deprecated.Earlier it used to work.However change it  `driver.SwitchToFrame "central-login-iframe"` selenium keep doing changes method and parameters and deprecate some method.

Answer (score 2):

The target element is in iframe so you have to switch to iframe before interacting with the target element.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the image and the explanation, I would have never figured that out by myself O:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Logindsfsdfsdfsdf()

    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

    driver.Get "https://partner.spreadshirt.de/login"
    driver.SwitchToFrame "central-login-iframe" ' .FindElementById("central-login-iframe")
    driver.FindElementByCss("#username").SendKeys ("username")
    driver.FindElementById("password").SendKeys "password"
    driver.FindElementById("login-submit").Click
    Stop
Stop
End Sub
```